# Qt unit-test: why "qmake" is not recognized

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I managed to follow [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html)  in order to write my first unit-test.

However, when opening a "cmd-console" from inside my project folder and try to rum qmake, i get the following error:

`'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

so, why qmake is not recognized? (note that I am working on windows Vita)

Comment: That tutorial tells you how to execute the unit tests. With wich of the points do you have problems? What output do you get if you call `make`/`nmake` like the tutorial tells you?

Comment: @ArneMertz: I don't call any make/nmake. My problem is when I run the code, which has no syntax error, nothing comes as how the test was run or if is successful or not (and I can assure you that when I change my Qstring in the QCOMPARE function to "hello" instead of "HELLO", nothing change) .. so I am doubting if I am missing something like may be it saves the result instead of showing it.

Comment: The .pro file from the tutorial is for symbian and maemo (mobile platforms). Is your .pro file made for your system?

Comment: @ariwez: if you wondering what is my "kit" ? it is a "Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit".

Comment: How do you "run the code"? The tutorial tells you to run make/nmake, to execute the tests, and that you then will get the test result as console output. If you don't run the make/nmake commands as specified and you don't get any output at all, one might suspect hat you are not really running the test program. I don't want to split hairs here, but you don't "run code" in C++. You *compile* the code to get a program, and you run that program. So I'm not sure what you are actually doing and what not. Maybe describe the detailed steps you take.

Comment: @hashDefine have you tried to compile and run the unit test example? It should be located in something like this: "\your_qt_lib_path\examples\qtestlib\tutorial1"

Comment: @ariwez: not yet but I will do now

Comment: @ArneMertz: I am using the word "run" to indicate the action of pressing the "play" icon in Qt in order to build my code in a debug mode. Regards the make/nmake, I tried to open a cmd console where my project is located and execute the three commands mentioned in the tutorials, but they are not executed because: `'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. now I don't know what to proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows qt and its tools are installed by default in `C:\Qt\blablah`. You should add the path to the qmake binary, and that will do the trick. See [the instructions here](https://superuser.com/questions/317631/setting-path-in-windows-7-command-prompt). Note that Qt creator set some variables for its terminal so you use qmake in creator without touching the system.

Comment: I could not find the qmake binary in the Qt folder.

Comment: for `5.14.2` is: `C:\Qt\Qt5.14.2\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\bin`

Answer (score 0):

set path the Qt compiler.

sth like this:

set PATH=C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin

where the 4.8.5 is the version of Qt you installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the QT bin path to PATH you can write the full path to qmake:

```
>"$(QTDIR)\bin\qmake.exe" -o Makefile odbc.pro
```

where $(QTDIR) is the full path of the qtbase directory.